# Wordpress plugin add text to frontend body homepage

Tags: wordpress

I am wordpress on a wordpress plugin and I need to add a message to the frontend page in the body of the homepage.

Right now if I add:

```
echo "My Message";
```

it is just added to the top of the backend.

How can I add a message to the homepage body frontpage?

Comment: In while file did you echo "My Message" ?

Comment: In the plugin main file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if something like this exists. How about using the `wp_head` hook to `echo` something just before the body? Or `wp_footer` hook to `echo` something just after the closing body tag?

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer